# insert into an array with a short and smart algorithm

Tags: objective-c

i need to sort my array with values that are in a certain positions, when the rest of them will have some initial position.
the way i do that is probably too long.

i have :

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        [whatBondInFrame addObject:@"no"];



        [whatBondInFrame insertObject:@"red" atIndex:0];
        [whatBondInFrame insertObject:@"red" atIndex:1];
        [whatBondInFrame insertObject:@"red" atIndex:2];
        [whatBondInFrame insertObject:@"gray" atIndex:10]; 
        [whatBondInFrame insertObject:@"gray" atIndex:11];
        [whatBondInFrame insertObject:@"gray" atIndex:12];
        [whatBondInFrame insertObject:@"red" atIndex:20];
        [whatBondInFrame insertObject:@"red" atIndex:21];
        [whatBondInFrame insertObject:@"red" atIndex:22];
```

its working but if i want to put more i will need more lines.
now if i use something like this :

```
whatBondInFrame = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Yellow", nil];
```

it will erase everything i had, AND here i cant put them in the right index.

is there another api to put objects at index in 1 line(such as this but with indexes ? )

A for loop is not good for this propose cause the elements are not symetric .

thanks .

Comment: Your question is not clear: I don't understand if you want to sort the array or just put a particular object in a specific position. What is your goal?

Comment: @Saphrosit my goal is to have an array of 100 indexes which at the start all of them are with the value @"no" , then after that, i want to change ONLY a certain indexes to the values i need, BUT to do that in one row.

Comment: 1) To change an entry, use [replaceObjectAtIndex:withIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:). 2) I still don't get what you mean with *"BUT to do that in one row."* Please explain in more details. Give an example or something.

Answer (score 1):

The closest api to what you want to do is `NSMutableArray`'s:

```
- (void)replaceObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withObjects:(NSArray *)objects
```

However there is no "one line" method to create an `NSIndexSet` from a collection of disjoint indices.

Are you really concerned over "one line" (and if so why?), or over maintaining a collection of constant index/value pairs to insert easily? If the latter you could use something like:

```
typedef struct { NSUInteger index, NSString *value } IndexValue;

IndexValue entries[] = { {0, @"red"}, {10, @"gray}, ... };

int count = sizeof(entries) / sizeof(IndexValue); // number of elements in the array
for(int ix = 0; ix < count; ix++)
   [whatBondInFrame replaceObjectAtIndex:entries[ix].index withObject:entries[ix].value];
```

Now you have a single place you define your index/value pairs which can easily be edited.